# C# Calculator - Can't insert a number before a decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, calculator

I have implemented a calculator in C# everything apart from this is working fine, basically if I try to enter a number before a decimal point the number is reset and only then lets me enter numbers after the decimal point I'm assuming this is something stupid and will be a quick fix but I'm having no luck

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GrantCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int count = 0;

        float result = 0;
        string operation = "";
        bool operationPressed = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }      

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //clearing result
            txtResult.Text = "0";
            result = 0;
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                //remove extra 0 
                if ((txtResult.Text == "0") || (operationPressed))
                {
                    txtResult.Clear();
                }
            }
           else if(count==1)
            {
                txtResult.Clear();
            }

            //event handler set for all  number buttons which goto result textbox
            operationPressed = false;
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            txtResult.Text += b.Text;
            count = 0;
        }

        private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            operation = b.Text;
            result = float.Parse(txtResult.Text);
            operationPressed = true;
           // count = 0;
        }

        private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (float.Parse(txtResult.Text) == 0 && operation == "/")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can't divide by 0");
            }

            //The math
            switch (operation)
                {
                    case "+":
                        txtResult.Text = (result + float.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        txtResult.Text = (result - float.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        txtResult.Text = (result * float.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        txtResult.Text = (result / float.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                        break;

                    case "%":
                        txtResult.Text = (result % float.Parse(txtResult.Text)).ToString();
                        break;
                    default:
                        txtResult.Text = "Invalid";
                        break;
                }
                count++;


        }

        private void txtResult_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char ch = e.KeyChar;
            if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            // to allow only one decimal
            if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }

        private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = new Button();

            string dot = txtResult.Text;

            if (dot.Contains("."))
            {
                txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + b.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text = ".";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line at the end:

`txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text = ".";`

The second `=` should be a `+`.

`a = b = c = d = 5;` notation is valid, and will set everything to `5`.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to [NibblyPig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55277991/1945525):

Why are you creating a new `Button` and why are you adding the `.Text` of that button (which is string.Empty since it hasn't been set) to `txtResult.Text` when it already contains a dot?

Optimized version would be:

```
private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!txtResult.Text.Contains("."))
    {
        txtResult.Text += ".";
    }
}
```